# Center libgdx stage object

Tags: java, libgdx

For a libgdx project, I want to have 3 images at the top centered side by side touching each other, but for some reason the middle one isn't centered and they won't go to the top. They are connected to the button "back" actor.

I tried:

```
Table table = new Table();
    table.setFillParent(true);
    table.setBackground(new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("background.png"))));
    table.padTop(50);
    table.add(characters).top().left();
    table.add(items).top();
    table.add(upgrades).top().right();
    table.row();
    table.bottom();
    table.add(back).size(back.getWidth(), back.getHeight()).colspan(2).padBottom(70);
    table.row();
    stage.addActor(table);
```

Comment: If your images have different widths, use .uniform() on the cells

Comment: It'd be a easier to answer if you would include a picture illustrating the problem or the result you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would illustrate somehow what are you trying to achive and what is your result, it would be easier to answer your question. (It's never too late to do so)

Anyway:
You have 3 images and you want them to be on top touching each other.

```
table.top();
table.add(characters).expandX().padTop(50);
table.add(items).expandX().padTop(50);
table.add(upgrades).expandX().padTop(50);//three images fill up total space given
```

Should give you the desired layout.

Turning on `table.setDebug(true);` will help you debugging by drawing debug lines around tables, cells and widgets.

If you are looking for more on topic there is an excellent wiki of `Table`: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table